# How to load File php in tcpdf

Tags: codeigniter, tcpdf

```
$tc="test tcpdf";
// print a block of text using Write()
$this->pdf->Write($h=0,$tc, $link='', $fill=0, $align='C', $ln=true,  $stretch=0, $firstline=true, $firstblock=false, $maxh=0);
```

I want to load view PHP in my codeigniter in TCPDF. I had success to export it from my string in my controller. But i want it to load from my view. Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: Please be more detailed what is your goal. You want to show "test tcpdf" in view or want to show PDF document in browser?